# Trying to make an UNO game but cant deal player hands

Tags: python, uno

In the dealCards function i tried to take 7 random cards from the deck list and append it to the hand1. But when i call the function, i indeed get 7 cards but not as string, i get them like this : "<**main**.UnoCard object at 0x00000202E461DF10>" How can i fix this issue?

```
import random

class UnoCard:
    def __init__(self, color, num):
        self.c = color
        self.n = num

    def __str__(self):
        return self.c + " " + str(self.n)

    def canplay(self, other):
        if self.c == other.c or self.n == other.n:
            return True
        else:
            return False


class CollectionOfUnoCards:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list1 = []

    def addCard(self, c):
        self.list1.append(c)

    def __str__(self):
        s = ""
        for card in self.list1:
            s += str(card) + "|"
        return s

    def makeDeck(self):
        colors = ["Yellow", "Blue", "Red", "Green"]
        numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

        for i in range(1, 3):
            for color in colors:
                for number in numbers:
                    card = UnoCard(color, number)
                    self.addCard(card)

    def shuffle(self):
        for i in range(1, 400):
            random_value = random.randint(0, 71)
            deck.list1[0], deck.list1[random_value] = deck.list1[random_value], deck.list1[0]

    def dealCards(self):
        hand1 = []
        for i in range(1, 8):
            random_value = random.randint(0, 71)
            hand1.append(deck.list1[random_value])
        print(hand1)

    def getNumCards(self):
        print(len(deck.list1))

    def getTopCard(self):
        print(deck.list1[-1])


deck = CollectionOfUnoCards()

deck.makeDeck()

deck.shuffle()

print(deck)



length = CollectionOfUnoCards()

length.getNumCards()

print(length)


last_card = CollectionOfUnoCards()

last_card.getTopCard()

print(last_card)



player1 = CollectionOfUnoCards()

player1.dealCards()

print(player1)
```

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" might help.

Comment: Printing an object uses `__repr__`, not `__str__`.